# Displaying a python list's values in HTML dropdown using AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am using Django and AJAX to implement a chained-dropdown. The user will first be prompted to select a brand_name from a dropdown, and depending upon the brand_name selected, all the names of the products that are made by that brand will be displayed in the second dropdown.

**views.py**

```
def chained_dropdown(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        brand = request.POST['brand']
        print(brand)

        sort_by_brand = list(models.Product.objects.filter(brand=brand).order_by('product_id').values('product_id', 'product_name'))

        data = {
            'SortByBrand': sort_by_brand
        }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**AJAX request:**

```
var brand = $('#brand').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/changeddropdown",
        data:{
            "brand": brand,
        }, success: function (data){
           
           // What should I do here?
 
           console.log(data)
        },
    })
```

**templates snippet:**
This is where I want the product names to be displayed, and the option value should be their corresponding product_id.

```
<label for="product_id"> Product ID</label>

<select name="product_id" id="product_id">

<option disabled selected="true"> --Select -- </option>

<option value=""> </option>

</select>
```

For your reference, this is what `console.log(data)` prints:

```
{SortByBrand: [{product_id: 31, product_name: "Lotion"}, {product_id: 32, product_name: "Deo"}]}
```

I am having trouble displaying this information in the template, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work

```
var brand = $('#brand').val()

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/changeddropdown",
    data:{
        "brand": brand,
    }, success: function (data){
       
       var select = document.getElementById("product_id");
       //clear previous data
       document.getElementById('product_id').innerText = null;
       data.SortByBrand.forEach(function(element, index, list) { 
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = element.product_name;
            option.value = element.product_id
            select.add(option, 0);
            list[index] = {'name': element}; 
        });

    },
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, but as I pointed out in the other answer, when I select another brand_name, the names of products belonging to the previously selected brand_name are still appearing too. Is there a way this can be fixed?

Comment: I have edited code to clear dropdown before populating it, hope it will work now

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the response in success callback of Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/changeddropdown",
    data:{
        "brand": brand,
    },
    success: function (data){
       console.log(data);

       // Add below snippet no
       let productSelectBox = $('#product_id');
       const productsData = data.SortByBrand;
       $.each(productsData, function(idx, product) {
           let productOption = $("<option/>", {
               value: product.product_id,
               text: product.product_name
           });
       
       productSelectBox.append(productOption);
       });
    }
});
```

Django view seems to be working. Although, you can improve your architecture by using Django REST Framework but this is not scope of this question.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a ton for your answer. It is working fine, but there's just one caveat. When I select "brand name 1" for the first time, it is displaying the product names correctly. However, when I select "brand name 2", the name of the products belonging to "brand name 1" are displayed along with that of "brand name 2".

I feel that this may be caused because of the append function, am I right?

The thing is, this is my first ever real project, and I had 0 experience with Django and everything related to web development up until about a week ago. I'll certainly checkout REST FW!

Comment: Hi.. you have to remove the existing options for brand 1 before issuing Ajax request for brand 2. You can write this code in beforeSend callback of Ajax. Just empty all the options from the select box.